# DLLImport(C code) C# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt”

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2010, dll

This is my DLL Import statement:

```
[DllImport("KaracellLib.dll", EntryPoint = "karacell_bridge@8", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int karacell_bridge(int argumentCount, string[] argContent);
```

The actual function definition in the native C code (which is converted to a DLL):

```
int __stdcall karacell_bridge(int argumentCount, char ** argContent )
```

When I try to call the DLL in my C# code more than once, I get the error mentioned.

I have tried the following to resolve the error

1. Suppress JIT optimization on module load(managed nly) by going into Tools -> Debugging -> General
2. Added ref in the C# dLL import definition: `public static extern int karacell_bridge(int argumentCount, ref string[] argContent);`

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `int` is not a function definition. (Hint: pay attention to the formatting!)

Comment: char ** argContent - show native C call to this function. Declaration is not enough to write correct code.

Comment: See if the problem happens when you try to access `argContent` in C or when you call the function from C#?

Comment: @AlvinWong: The exception is an AccessViolationException for when I call the DLL...

Comment: @AlexFarber: Do you require the karacell_bridge function? It spans over 100 over lines..

Comment: You mean the first time you call it doesn't crash? What if you do nothing at all in `karacell_bridge` (just return at first) does it still crash?

Comment: Hey! The problem isn't actually with the karacell_bridge..I just figured the bug. Have explained in the answer..Thanks a ton for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because multiple threads were calling the karacell_bridge function in the C# program. Hence, once I took care of it, the exception was fixed :)